# sending messages to a websocket server using em-websocket-client

Tags: ruby, websocket

I am new to websockets and am trying to send messages to an existing websocket server that expects a subscription request. I tried:

```
require 'em-websocket-client'

EM.run do
  ws = EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect("ws://localhost:3000")
  ws.send_msg "this is a test message"
end
```

but I get

```
'undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass'.
```

I can read streaming data correctly from the server by replacing the send_mess line with

```
  ws.stream do |msg|
    puts "received msg <#{msg}>"
  end
```

So at least I know that I am connecting correctly to the server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have to put the call to `send_msg` inside a `WebSocketClient` `callback` function, like this:

```
require 'em-websocket-client'

EM.run do
  ws = EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect("ws://localhost:3000")
  ws.callback do
      ws.send_msg "this is a test message"
  end
end
```

See [this](https://github.com/mwylde/em-websocket-client) for more (but, unfortunately, not enough) information.